# Cisco ASA Hung - Error: "i82546GB/enadap_get: 2 not null"

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall

We configured our new cisco ASA 5520 firewall device to act as RAVPN peer device. AAA is configured in such a way that user will get authenticate at our ACS 5.4 server. After completion of all other RAVPN related configurations, we tested aaa authentication for specific user ID and it was successful.

Upon successful aaa test, we initiated the actual RAVPN traffic from Internet hosted windows machine through cisco vpn client. The connectivity was successful but after few seconds, the vpn connectivity got disconnected.

When verified at ASA, it was hung with last shown error as:

```
i82546GB/enadap_get: 1 not null.
```

Google referred the similar error occurrence with PIX firewalls but not with ASA. No solutions/suggestions available for those pix occurrences too.

Tried below options but ended in no positive result

- IOS upgrade from 8.0(4) to 8.2.5(33) (Interim stable version with pre 8.3 IOS versions of ASA.)
- Firewall reboot
- Cleared complete configuration and tried re-building once.

Suggestions or solution for this is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obvious answer: ASK CISCO (you do have a support contract for that ASA???)